# Trigger a button click inside a jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

it is a very simple question that I'm not finding an answer for it. I have a dialog and in some events happening inside the dialog I want to click one of the dialog buttons. The code which defines the dialog is:

```
var dialog = $('<div>').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title : title,
    resizable : false,
    buttons : {
        'CANCEL' : {
            text : messages.Cancel,
            click : function(){$(this).dialog('close')}
        },
        'OK' : {
            text : messages.Ok,
            click : okButtonCallback
        }
    }
});
```

and in my event I can get the dialog, find the buttons but I can not trigger the click event with right reference passed as this. I do this:

```
buttons = dialog.dialog('option', 'buttons');
```

and I have the buttons each of them has the click function. If called directly or through trigger('click'), they call the click event of button but with the button itself as this not the dialog object.
I saw somewhere to call

```
buttons['OK'].apply(dialog);
```

but my buttons have absolutely no apply function!

I'm not sure what can I do!

Comment: If you can get a reference to the button it should be as simple as button.click(); or $(button).click();

Comment: as stated in question, it does not pass the right reference as this inside the function.

Comment: i'm a little late on this, but oddly enough i did it your way, "buttons['Ok'].apply(dialog);" and it worked. i tried "buttons['Ok'].click.apply(dialog);" but it didn't work.

Comment: Same here - "buttons['OK'].apply(dialog)" is what worked for me too.

Comment: tooooo late, but probably this is because of some browser dependent or even maybe because of jQuery version. but the response is true, buttons['OK'] is an object and apply can be called on functions not objects.

Comment: according to new Jquery UI documentation, you need to retrieve a button from array with index like buttons[1].click.apply(dialog);

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, you need to get `buttons[0]` not `buttons['OK']`, then, it's not a function it's an object, try to get to click function like this :

```
buttons[0].click.apply(dialog);
```

Comment: oh no, for my case, latest jquery ui (june 2019), it's buttons.OK and not buttons[0]. Further more, buttons.OK is a function.

Answer (score 15):

```
$('.ui-button:contains("Ok")').click()
```

Comment: I'm using this particularly for testing in qUnit, and it's invaluable!

Comment: I think you didn't read the last part of my question, the click() function or trigger('click') works but when doing it like that **this** inside the click function does not refer to dialog (as it refers to when user clicks on button) but refers to button itself. my problem was how to overcome this difference and I solved it.

Answer (score 6):

What I use is:

```
// Get the buttons
var buttons = $("#myDialog").dialog("option", "buttons");
// Calls the event
buttons["OK"]();
```

Comment: i call 'close' inside 'OK', and error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'